# Flex: DataGrid column formatting of numbers

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm trying to format some numbers in a column of a DataGrid. I'm getting an error in my simplified test program below when I run it. All the examples I've seen so far have column data that are strings. Is there a way to do it using numbers? How to modify the code below to format the `checking` values?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[       
        [Bindable]
        public var checking:Array = new Array(1000000.2222, 0, 1000);

        private function myLabelFunction(item:Array, column:DataGridColumn):String {    
                var result:String;
                result = myFormatter.format(item);
                return result;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <s:NumberFormatter id="myFormatter"
                       fractionalDigits="2" 
                       decimalSeparator="."
                       groupingSeparator=","
                       useGrouping="true"
                       negativeNumberFormat="0"
                       />
</fx:Declarations>

<mx:DataGrid id="dg1" dataProvider="{checking}" >

    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="checking" headerText="Checking" 
                           labelFunction="myLabelFunction" />
    </mx:columns>

</mx:DataGrid>

</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change filter function signature (`item` should be `Object`)

   `private function myLabelFunction(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String`
2. Remove `dataField="checking"` from column.

Answer (score 1):

While the label function will certainly work -- I usually prefer an ItemRenderer for things like this. You override the render function and then you can display whatever it is in the grid view "box" however you like.

A decent example is [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html). Scroll down about 1/4 the way down for a DataGrid example.

Comment: Nice to know, thanks. If I have an ItemRenderer already (not shown) for other reasons, can I just add a formatter to it somehow so I don't need to write another ItemRenderer? What would I need to change/add?

Comment: That example uses an inline item render, those are directly tied to columns they're "inline" with. You can use an external item renderer (usually in its own script file) and tie that to as many columns as you'd like. You just write functions to properly manipulate the data. You only get the data object with an item renderer though, so figuring out exactly what to do can be tricky.

Comment: I guess my question was, what control would I use in the ItemRenderer to do the formatting? For example, to change the text color I'd use <s:Label ... />. What control would I use to place the NumberFormatter inside?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I found an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471477/how-can-i-create-a-custom-mxadvanceddatagriditemrenderer-in-flex4

Answer (score 0):

In case of object you must use/No caso de objeto, deve-se usar:

```
        private function myLabelFunction(item:Object, column:GridColumn):String {    
            var result:String;
            result = myFormatter.format(item[column.dataField]);
            return result;
        }
```