# How to modify a column in an Adobe Flex datagrid, populated with data from a database

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

In another application I have retrieved and stored a user's data, including their date of birth. In this application i'm making a call to the database and populating my datagrid with that information. I'd like to display the user's age though instead of their DOB. I was wondering if it's possible to modify the column so it will display this.

If it's not possible I will have to calculate this and store the user's age in the database, but I feel it is not the best solution as their age will change and the DOB won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would add an item renderer to the column in question, you can then manipulate the data as you see fit. You can take the DOB value and do simple math to figure out the user's age.

Scroll about 1/4 way down the DataGrid section:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html

You could also use a label function to do this -- similar to what is asked in this question from only a few hours ago:

[Flex: DataGrid column formatting of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454932/flex-datagrid-column-formatting-of-numbers/10456262#10456262)

Comment: Thankyou for the response. I understand the concept, but because i'm a newbie I'm not sure how to implement it. Do you have an example for a spark datagrid? I'm not sure if I use exactly the same tags but with s instead of mx. I'm populating the rows with the following:
`<s:AsyncListView list="{getUserResult.lastResult}"/>`

Comment: Sure (more or less the same): http://butterfliesandbugs.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/using-a-datefield-itemrenderer-for-a-spark-datagrid/. Please upvote and/or accept answers you find helpful

Comment: Actually, whilst I have your attention I'd like to ask a similar question: Is it possible to have a column in the datagrid that does not get its data from my database? I want to display a user's facebook picture, without storing them in my database. I know this is possible by accessing a URL that I have, but part of the URL will need to be replaced with the user's facebook ID, which is being populated into the datagrid.

Comment: Yes, you just do a different renderer for that column. Bind it to whatever data you have (you can bind multiple columns to the same value) and use the renderer to output the correct result.

Comment: I've done as suggested. Inside my Gridcolumn tag I've added the following tags: `<s:ItemRenderer>`, `<fx:Component>`, `<s:GridItemRenderer>`, then my image:
`<s:Image id="fbImg" source="http://graph.facebook.com/{getUserResult.lastResult.facebookid}/picture?type=normal"/>`
It works when I put a static URL, but not when I try to modify part of the URL for the users facebook image. I'm getting this error:
`1120: Access of undefined property getUserResult`.
I don't understand because this works elsewhere.

Comment: I even tried this:
`<s:Image id="fbImg" source="{'http://graph.facebook.com/' + getUserResult.lastResult.facebookid + '/picture?type=normal'}"/>`

Comment: The item renderer operates on a single piece of data, you need to override the set data as shown in the link I posted or use that in your source link -- try `.../{data}/picture`

Comment: Using `{data.facebookid}` solved it. Thankyou very much once again!